# Why can you assign to NotImplemented?

Tags: python-3.x, variable-assignment

In Python 3, you can't assign to `True`, `False`, or `None`. But, on CPython at least, you can assign to `NotImplemented`.

```
>>> False
False
>>> False = 42
SyntaxError: can't assign to keyword                                                                      '
>>> NotImplemented
NotImplemented
>>> NotImplemented = 42
>>> NotImplemented
42
```

What is the reasoning behind this?

Answer (score 0):

The Python constants [enumerated here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/constants.html) are not "constant" (they can be reassigned) save for the ones that explicitly say: "Assignments to X are illegal and raise a SyntaxError." These are: `False`, `True`, `None` and `__debug__`. This is explicitly pointed out in a note:

> The names `None`, `False`, `True` and `__debug__` cannot be reassigned
>   (assignments to them, even as an attribute name, raise SyntaxError),
>   so they can be considered “true” constants.

It's worth noting that [assigning to `__debug__` only became illegal in version 2.7](https://docs.python.org/2/library/constants.html) and `False` and `True` later on. It's possible in a further version it may be illegal to assign to `NotImplemented`.